# Why does lang sass not work in. vue style tag?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I had already installed sass-loader and node-sass in my project but when I use `<style lang="sass">` in my vue file that style didn't complied by the way style was work fine without `lang="sass"` attribute. Is there I miss some step?

Comment: See this - [vue-loader-css-extraction](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html)

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: give it a try `<style lang="scss">`

Comment: @sugars
 I can't find vue-loader-css-extraction from this link
@The_ehT
I don't get any error
@SJ_OWOW
It will be get error when I use ```<style lang="scss">```

Comment: If no error, how are you determining that the style didn't compile?

Comment: @tony19 I write some css but It was never effected on my page then I going to the devtool to check out whether those css are show up in the document but I can't find them

Comment: That doesn't necessarily imply the style doesn't compile. Can you provide a reproducible example in Codesandbox?

Comment: Sorry I am using not sass but scss that It still don't working

I code like
```<style lang="scss" scoped>
       ...some Class
    </style>```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It is a MiniCssExtractPlugin Plugin Issue You need to set up `webpack.conf` like below

```
module: {
        rules: [
                   ...,
                   {
                        loader: 
                            process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
                                ? 'vue-style-loader'
                                : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                            reloadAll: true,
                        },
                    }
]}
```